# How to write the Backand Code for an Android App For AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, cloud

my boss has told me to shift all works to the AWS, and I'M facing a lot of problem in gathering information from web.
If anyone can help me out from this trap, it would be very helpful.

I have an Android App(Feedback app), Whenever a person gives feedback the result should store in AWS database.

Q1: What services do i need to use for the whole process
Q2: Where did i need to write the codes for this.

Comment: Your boss is one lucky fellow!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of database services on AWS, and the one you choose depends on your use case and application design. You might want to consider RDS or DynamoDB, and should research both to see which meets your needs. For DynamoDB you can use the [AWS SDK for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/). Take a look at the [DynamoDB section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) for instructions on getting started